# python pass function arguments outside function

Tags: python, function, arguments

My code is designed like this

```
while True:

    globvar = 0
    def test(self, response):
      #something
      callback=self.set_globvar_to_one

    def set_globvar_to_one(self, response):
      global globvar
      globvar = raw_input("Please enter 'hello':")

    set_globvar_to_one()

    if globvar.strip() == 'hello':
        continue
    else:
        print 'Goodbye'
        break
```

But I get the following error

> TypeError: set_globvar_to_one() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

**Update:**
i want to get the globvar varible that is assign in the function, and use it out side of the function 
problem is the arguments isn't defined outside of functions

Comment: Why have you got two separate functions with the same name?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve but you are obviously not heading in the right direction... You should explain the real problem you're trying to solve (and the context) instead.

Comment: yea what @brunodesthuilliers said without the full picture it's pretty hard to see what you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: cool not that you have edited it seem my edited answer @kim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As explained prior, it was mainly because you were not passing the correct number of arguments to the function.

See the following code which should do what you want (get the value of globvar set within the function):

```
   while True:

      globvar = 0

      def test(self, response):
        #something
        callback=self.set_globvar_to_one

      def set_globvar_to_one(self, response):
        global globvar
        globvar = raw_input("Please enter 'hello':")

      set_globvar_to_one("self","response")

      if globvar.strip() == "hello":
        continue
      else:
        print 'Goodbye'
        break
```

Comment: the error doesn't even occur there. It's on line 12 at the set_globvar_to_one()

Comment: wait...so you know this yet you aren't giving it any arguments?....The issue still remains it needs two arguments.

Comment: In Python a function is an object so it's perfectly legal to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the function `set_globvar_to_one` to receive 2 arguments `self` and `response`.

But when you are calling it on line 12 you are not passing any arguments to it 
    set_globvar_to_one()

Add the two arguments and your problem will go away.

```
set_globvar_to_one(self, response)
```

Comment: but then i get NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Is this part of a larger class? self is usually reserved to denote instance of a class for functions of that class to use. Can you post more context around what you are trying to do. I see no need for response to be included in the arguments for set_globvar_to_one

Answer (score 0):

Just below your function definition, you're calling the raw function `set_globvar_to_one()`, and that too without any arguments. Since you're passing self as the first argument in the definition, I assume this block is within a `class` definition.

So you should try something like `self.set_globvar_to_one(response)` instead of just `set_globvar_to_one()`.

P.S: I don't see any need of `response` in the definition of `set_globvar_to_one`. Furthermore, it would be a better coding practice to define this function outside the loop.